# Is there disadvantage in building with -g -O and strip vs. building only with -O

Tags: c, gcc

I have a C code executable for Linux.

For release, I can have two options:

One is build with -g -O3, strip the debug (strip -g) and send the output as release.
Second is build the release directly with -O3.

The advantage of the first option, if I understand correctly, is that I can use the exe before the stripping for remote debugging or for analyzing core dumps.

The question is if there is any disadvantages in this approachi.e., is there run time performance overhead of building with -g and then stripping

thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that optimization is allowed to heavily rewrite your code as long as it is semantically the same; and does so very aggressively. So even with debug information present the compiled code may not match your source code very well making debugging "challenging". Have a look at the documentation of the various individual optimization switches in GCC to get an idea of how much code can change.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of this issue, but still it is easier to debug this than debug the bare optimized executable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no run time performance hit for using `-g`. The debug info lives in a separate section of the executable, which wont even be loaded if you execute the file.

But you can separate debug info and executables if you wish (which still won't make any performance difference). My Gentoo Linux handles it this way, the reason is simply minimizing used disk space which allows me having all binaries on a small fast disk while still keeping the debug info, which is alomst never used, in a separate partition.

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug foo foo.debug
strip -g foo
```

Now you have a foo executable and a foo.debug which contains debug symbols.

Comment: @Haendel: in the lifecycle of every newer, faster disk technology, there's a brief period in which the price of a disk big enough to contain an OS installation is painful ;-) Also, the smaller and cheaper the device, the longer this period lasts since the cost of the fancy fast disk is more compared with overall cost.

Comment: A more attractive advantage of this is for distributions to have a package with only binaries, and another package with only debug info. Only a few users have to download the second one, and for those, it is much better than downloading a separate package with binary+debug that have to replace the former.